# Complexity of Finding a line graph of graph G?

Tags: graph-theory

I am just curious weather this is polynomial, or exponential, or something else?

Comment: This question needs more detail to be comprehensible. Revise and you may get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity should be quadratic (i.e., polynomial) in the number of edges: for each pair of edges, we check if they share an endpoint, and if they do, we add an edge to the line graph.

Since the number of edges is at most quadratic in the number of vertices, the complexity of computing the line graph should be quartic in the number of vertices.

I say "should be" above because the answer might depend on the coding used for the input graph (e.g. edge list, table of adjacencies, adjacency matrix), but sensible encodings should result in quadratic time in the number of edges.